# phpQuery returning wrong results with regex

Tags: regex, phpquery

```
    $html = '<html>
                <body>
                    <div id="dupe_1">1
                        <div class="dupe_1.1">1.1</div>
                        <div id="dupe_1.2">1.2</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dupe_2">2
                        <div class="dupe_2.1">2.1</div>
                        <div id="dupe_2.2">2.2</div>
                        <div>extra</div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>';
    $html = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
    $node = pq('div:regex(id,^dupe_\d+$)',$html);
    echo count($node);
```

This returns 7 that is all divs. It should return only 2 divs (dupe_1 and dupe_2)

Comment: I don't see `:regex` in the phpQuery selector documentation https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Selectors

Comment: @Barmar I guess it has an implementation for it. If not can you suggest a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid doing things like that, you should be able to get those with css:

```
[id*=dupe_]:not([id*="."])
```